# Pop named route

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Sometimes it is useful to pop a route that is not the current, or maybe when you have pushed several routes and alertDialogs and you might want to pop one route that's under the current.

Is there any way to pop a named route?

Comment: Useful like what ? The navigator don't let you pop a route that is not the current or until you reach a known named route. In my opinion, you have to think differently like using pushReplacementNamed method or else

Comment: @FPerroch let's say I have processes that automatically display dialogs or modals. There might be a point where I have 2 modals at the same time and I don't want to just pop them both.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a Navigation concern but a question about having 2 modals at the same time. Post some code of your and I'll could help you maybe :)

Comment: @FPerroch I don't have a small piece of code I could share, as it involves a bigger effort, but basically, using BloC pattern, I have a modal that pops up when a state in BlocA happens and another one modal that pops up when BlocB state happens. These two states could happen at the same time and maybe BlocA state is already handled but BlocB state isn't. BlocA modal appeared first and BlocB modal after, so I want to be able to pop BlocA modal and leave BlocB modal. But if any of my checks does a `Navigator.pop`, my BlocB modal disappears (maybe unhandled) and BlocA stays (which should go away)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't pop an element from Navigator history's stack which is not the current. the Navigator 2.0 will implement this feature but its milestone is scheduled for august 2020 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45938. Until then, I have no more solutions. Maybe you can pop the BlocA modal before displaying the BLocB one

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: I want to pop all the routes with a certain name. Can you suggest me some workaround?